# postgres timerange that goes to the next day

Tags: postgresql, datetimerangefield

start time '22:00'
end time '3:00'

```sql
select time '22:00' - time '3:00' --result interval -18 h<br />
SELECT 24 -  (abs(extract(hour from time '1:00'  - time '22:00' ))) -- returns 3
```

finally
how to create this timerange knowing that endtime of '3:00' [upper bound] is less than [lower bound] '22:00'

### FYI

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ext.time_subtype_diff(x time, y time) RETURNS float8 AS 
'SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (x - y))' LANGUAGE sql STRICT IMMUTABLE;

CREATE TYPE ext.timerange AS RANGE (
    subtype = time,
    subtype_diff = time_subtype_diff
);
```

Comment: All of the sketched solutions and even your question do not deal with edge cases! Think of dayshift times. In that case 02:10 might be after 02:50. I just want to say: Be careful what you do!

Comment: @S-Man [mine does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78026132/5298879), `tstzrange` type does handle DST. Thanks for raising the point - double-checking my answer because of that allowed me to fix the custom range type demo to use `timetz` instead of previous `time` to make it consistent with the `tstzrange` in that manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `timerange` [range data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) based on `time` (of day, without date). Closest thing is `tsrange`, which includes dates. It's best to always use the [timezone-aware](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29) variant: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QYZPNiEs)

```sql
select tstzrange('today'::date   +'22:00'::time,
                 'tomorrow'::date+'03:00'::time);
```

| tstzrange |
| --- |
| ["2024-02-20 22:00:00+00","2024-02-21 03:00:00+00") |

Depending on what you plan to do with it, you could also [`create type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) of your own, setting it up as your desired *range based on `time`*. This would automatically create a multirange version of it and give you access to all [built-in functions and operators, like `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xkqxIqS1)

```sql
create type ttzrange as range(subtype=timetz);
--above automatically creates `ttzmultirange` variant

create table test (tmr ttzmultirange);

insert into test 
select ttzmultirange(ttzrange('22:00','24:00'),ttzrange('00:00','05:00')) as ttzmr;

select ttzmr @> '01:00'::timetz as "is 1 o'clock in range" from test;
```

| is 1 o'clock in range |
| --- |
| t |

You need the multirange for these to span "multiple days" - which isn't entirely valid interpretation, as `time` isn't supposed to be aware of `date`. Aside from the huge benefit of having built-ins at disposal, this also enables you to accommodate mid-day breaks in your ranges - the range crossing midnight is actually two ranges, one early in the small hours, one late evening up to midnight, with a long break in between.

---

You could also split the value into separate fields, or create a plain, non-range type with the start/end `time` fields:

```
create type timerange as(start_time time, end_time time);
select ('22:00','03:00')::timerange;
```

| row |
| --- |
| (22:00:00,03:00:00) |

For some purposes it might be easier to hold only the start `time` and duration `interval`:

```sql
create type timerange2 as(start_time time, duration interval);
```

Which doesn't help much in containment/overlap checks (2 o'clock should be in the first range, but it's still ToD vs ToD, assuming no difference in date, since it's unaware of dates):

```sql
select (tr2), 
       (tr2).start_time, 
       (tr2).duration,
       (tr2).start_time+(tr2).duration as end_time,
       '02:00' between (tr2).start_time 
                   and (tr2).start_time+(tr2).duration as "2 o'clock in range"
from test2;
```

| tr2 | start_time | duration | end_time | 2 o'clock in range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (22:00:00,05:00:00) | 22:00:00 | 05:00:00 | 03:00:00 | **F** |
| (04:00:00,01:30:00) | 04:00:00 | 01:30:00 | 05:30:00 | **F** |

The non-range approach forces you to emulate or re-implement the built-in functions and operators and/or address the range bounds "manually".

Comment: i've been studying your solution 
('22:00','24:00') fixes my issue I can have as many timeranges as I please thx

Answer (score 0):

Simple example

```
create table test (id int,start_time time,end_time time);
insert into test values
 (1,'22:00','3:00')
,(2,'22:00','23:00')
,(3,'22:00','24:00')
;
select * from test;
select *
  ,end_time-start_time diff1
  ,end_time-start_time
   +case when end_time<start_time then '24:00'::time
    else '00:00'::time
    end
    diff2
from test;
```

Output

| id | start_time | end_time | diff1 | diff2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22:00:00 | 03:00:00 | -19:00:00 | 05:00:00 |
| 2 | 22:00:00 | 23:00:00 | 01:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
| 3 | 22:00:00 | 24:00:00 | 02:00:00 | 02:00:00 |